# Remove item from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel and PHP. In my project (Laravel 7), I use this component: https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset

I need a function to delete the selected branch (record) along with the records "deep".

Normally, I make something like this:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, int $parentId, int $id)
{
    $node = $this->model->where('id', $id)->get();
    $this->model->where('id',$value)->delete();
}
```

But in the manual, https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset, I found this:

Deleting nodes To delete a node:

$node->delete(); IMPORTANT! Any descendant that node has will also be deleted!

IMPORTANT! Nodes are required to be deleted as models, don't try do delete them using a query like so:

```
Category::where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
```

How should I change my code to? Did the deletion work correctly?

How can I correctly remove my items?

Comment: How it comes `$value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eloquent like this:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, int $parentId, int $id){  
    $data = Model::findOrFail($id)->delete();
}
```

It will work!

Comment: yes, it's work. Byt it Will this not interfere with "IMPORTANT! Nodes are required to be deleted as models, don't try to delete them using a query like so:Category :: where ('id', '=', $ id) -> delete ();" ??

Comment: Will your deletion not interfere with the deletion described in the documentation: https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset?